# Not able to pass value with href using $_GET

Tags: php

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($run))
            {

            $sum= $sum+$row[6];

            $id=$row[2];
```

?>

```
         <tr>
             <th><?php echo $row[2];?></th>
             <th><?php echo $row[5];?></th>
             <th><?php echo $row[6];?></th>
            <td><a href='cart-remove.php?id=".$id."'> Remove</a></td>
         </tr>
```

What I am trying to do is fetching row from database and getting id of an item and then am passing that id to next page so that I can delete that very item from cart, but I dont know why I am not able to pass that id value to the next page am using href for that and `$_GET` method. 
After executing the code am getting `http://localhost/layout/cart-remove.php?id=%22.$id.%22`
But if I use `cart-remove.php?id=2`code is working just fine. of-course 2 is already an item in cart.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong.

Change the HTML to:

```
     <tr>
         <th><?php echo $row[2];?></th>
         <th><?php echo $row[5];?></th>
         <th><?php echo $row[6];?></th>
        <td><a href='cart-remove.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'> Remove</a></td>
     </tr>
```

You are not echoing the variable :)

Comment: It's similar to how you echo the top rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing in `href`. You can use as below.

```
href='cart-remove.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'
```

or shorthand style:

```
href='cart-remove.php?id=<?= $id ?>'
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please do some correction before try to get url parameter from cart-remove.php page using $_GET;

```
    <!--Please follow below correction-->

    <tr>
         <th><?php echo $row['id'];?></th>
         <th><?php echo $row[5];?></th>
         <th><?php echo $row[6];?></th>
        <td><a href='cart-remove.php?id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Remove</a></td>
     </tr>
```

and after that i hope you will find your solution on cart-remove.php page by using $_GET['id']; if you still don't get your answer let me know i will do the needful for you.